# java.lang.SecurityExcption: WifiService: Neither usr 10140 nor curent proces hs andrid.prmission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, manifest, android-permissions

I am trying to create an Android plugin for Unity to get the WiFi information from the Android device, When I try to run the app on my android device it crashes. Let me know if I am doing something wrong or all wrong, all suggestions are welcome.

Target SDK version: 21
running on Android version 8.0.0

Thanks!
[Manifest File Location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jumx.jpg): AndroidProjects\pluginlibrary\src\main

[Manifest File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMAQS.jpg)

```
`<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.pluginlibrary" >
    <!--dangerous permission-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
</manifest>`
```

[Android Plugin Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8pgR.jpg)

```
package com.example.pluginlibrary;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.net.wifi.ScanResult;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity;

import java.util.List;

public class PluginTest extends UnityPlayerActivity {

    private Context context;
    WifiManager wifiManager;
    private static PluginTest instance;

    public PluginTest() {
        this.instance = this;
    }

    public static PluginTest instance() {
        if (instance == null) {
        instance = new PluginTest();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public void setContext(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void ShowMessage(String message) {
        Toast.makeText(this.context, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public String GetWifiInformation() {
        Log.d("Unity", "GetWifiInformation: ");

        wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        BroadcastReceiver wifiScanReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {
                boolean success = intent.getBooleanExtra(
                        WifiManager.EXTRA_RESULTS_UPDATED, false);
                if (success) {
                    scanSuccess();
                } else {
                    // scan failure handling
                    scanFailure();
                }
            }
        };

        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION);
        context.registerReceiver(wifiScanReceiver, intentFilter);

        boolean success = wifiManager.startScan();
        if (!success) {
            // scan failure handling
            scanFailure();
        }
        Log.d("Unity", "Getring return value");

        return "";
    }

    private void scanSuccess() {
        List<ScanResult> results = wifiManager.getScanResults();
        // get the BSSID from the scan results
    }

    private void scanFailure() {
        // handle failure: new scan did NOT succeed
        // consider using old scan results: these are the OLD results!
        List<ScanResult> results = wifiManager.getScanResults();
    }

    public void GetMessageFromUnity() {
        Log.d("Unity", "GetMessageFromUnity: ");
    }
}
```

`

`Android Plugin Class continued`[Android Plugin Class Continued](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFEwy.jpg)

[Error Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbtPm.jpg) `

```
09-29 13:48:00.339 25438-25455/? A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:504] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI FindClass called with pending exception java.lang.SecurityException: WifiService: Neither user 10140 nor current process has android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE.
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at void android.os.Parcel.readException(int, java.lang.String) (Parcel.java:1959)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at void android.os.Parcel.readException() (Parcel.java:1905)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at void android.net.wifi.IWifiManager$Stub$Proxy.startScan(android.net.wifi.ScanSettings, android.os.WorkSource, java.lang.String) (IWifiManager.java:1607)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at boolean android.net.wifi.WifiManager.startScan(android.os.WorkSource) (WifiManager.java:1838)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at boolean android.net.wifi.WifiManager.startScan() (WifiManager.java:1829)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at java.lang.String com.example.pluginlibrary.PluginTest.GetWifiInformation() (PluginTest.java:84)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at boolean com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.nativeRender() ((null):-2)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at boolean com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.c(com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer) ((null):-1)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at boolean com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$e$2.queueIdle() ((null):-1)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at android.os.Message android.os.MessageQueue.next() (MessageQueue.java:394)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:142)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at void com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$e.run() ((null):-1)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504] 
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]     in call to FindClass
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]     from boolean com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.nativeRender()
    java_vm_ext.cc:504] "UnityMain" prio=5 tid=13 Runnable
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 flags=0 obj=0x181c05f8 self=0xdd87ea00
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   | sysTid=25455 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xcffff970
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   | state=R schedstat=( 692579348 31631464 1032 ) utm=53 stm=16 core=6 HZ=100
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   | stack=0xcfefd000-0xcfeff000 stackSize=1038KB
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   | held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #00 pc 002c4afb  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art15DumpNativeStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEEEEiP12BacktraceMapPKcPNS_9ArtMethodEPv+130)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #01 pc 003565a1  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread9DumpStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEbP12BacktraceMapb+200)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #02 pc 00352a73  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread4DumpERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEbP12BacktraceMapb+34)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #03 pc 0022fff5  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art9JavaVMExt8JniAbortEPKcS2_+736)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #04 pc 002303eb  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art9JavaVMExt9JniAbortVEPKcS2_St9__va_list+58)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #05 pc 000d286f  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ScopedCheck6AbortFEPKcz+46)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #06 pc 000d2407  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ScopedCheck11CheckThreadEP7_JNIEnv+354)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #07 pc 000d0c05  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ScopedCheck5CheckERNS_18ScopedObjectAccessEbPKcPNS_12JniValueTypeE+604)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #08 pc 000bd8f7  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8CheckJNI9FindClassEP7_JNIEnvPKc+450)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #09 pc 00452378  /data/app/com.CJ.AndroidPLugin-BqvsV8_-skC366qUka3LQA==/lib/arm/libunity.so (???)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #10 pc 00442108  /data/app/com.CJ.AndroidPLugin-BqvsV8_-skC366qUka3LQA==/lib/arm/libunity.so (???)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #11 pc 0000296b  /data/app/com.CJ.AndroidPLugin-BqvsV8_-skC366qUka3LQA==/oat/arm/base.odex (Java_com_unity3d_player_UnityPlayer_nativeRender__+74)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.nativeRender(Native method)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.c(unavailable:-1)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$e$2.queueIdle(unavailable:-1)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:394)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:142)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$e.run(unavailable:-1)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]
```

[Unity Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ly3vq.jpg)`

```
public class PluginWrapper : MonoBehaviour {

    private AndroidJavaObject androidInstance = null;
    private AndroidJavaObject activityContext = null;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        if (androidInstance == null)
        {
            using (AndroidJavaClass activityClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer"))
            {
                activityContext = activityClass.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
            }

            using (AndroidJavaObject pluginClass = new AndroidJavaObject("com.example.pluginlibrary.PluginTest"))
            {
                if (pluginClass != null)
                {
                    androidInstance = pluginClass.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("instance");
                    androidInstance.Call("setContext", activityContext);
                    androidInstance.Call("GetMessageFromUnity");
                    androidInstance.Call<string>("GetWifiInformation");
                    activityContext.Call("runOnUiThread", new AndroidJavaRunnable(() =>
                    {
                        androidInstance.Call("ShowMessage", "Plugin Active!");
                    }));
                }
            }
        }
        //androidJavaClass = new AndroidJavaObject("com.example.pluginlibrary.PluginTest");
        //androidJavaClass.Call("GetMessageFromUnity");
    }
```

`

Comment: 1.Post the plugin code. 2.Copy and post the exception or crash log. They are required in order to help you

Comment: I have added the snapshots of the code, manifest, and error log.

Comment: Notice how there is no mention of snapshot/screenshot in my comment.....

Comment: Updated @Programmer

Comment: Where did you put the Manifest file? A screenshot of that that location where it resides would be helpful

Comment: @Programmer: AndroidProjects\pluginlibrary\src\main, added the screenshot as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the first line and the most important part of the error:

> A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:504] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI
>   FindClass called with pending exception java.lang.SecurityException:
>   WifiService: Neither user 10140 nor current process has
>   android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE.

You have to copy the `AndroidManifest.xml` file with the permission into your Unity project. That should be placed in the `<UnityProjectName>Assets\Plugins\Android`. If you're still getting the exact exception above, it means that you have not done this properly. You must spell the folder names correctly.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked, I didn't know that we also have to add the manifest in unity plugin folder. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: New Unity plugin users wouldn't know that. I suggest the first thing you do when you have a problem with a Unity java plugin is to check the log. It's very important. It's usually, permission issue, activity/context null issue or function spelling mismatch issues (mentioned in order). Checking the error log will save you time which this alone cost you 2 days. You're welcome!